# Copying link text as you click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a website with various links on it.  I would like to know if it is possible to code the links in a fashion where once a user clicks on the link, the link text is copied to the user's clipboard while the opening of the link is initiated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar Q : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Bad idea #302,234,554. Funny enough, almost all are Javascript related.

Comment: Bottom line is that you'd need Flash for anything reliable.

Answer (score 1):

http://zeroclipboard.org/

You can use Zero Clipboard to do the copying and set the onclick handler of the link.

`<a onclick="copyMyText(this)" href="url">Text here</a>`

Comment: Thanks, Looking into ZeroClipboard at the moment.  Seems like the only decent cross-browser solution out there. And yes, I and looking for both a copying of the link text, while also initiating a href.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but only reliable if you use flash which is a big downfall, there are libraries like zero clipboard that are good for this, but other than that its quite a tedious job. This cant be done cross browser with javascript